# Test fails because of missing links that however are there in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

The test below generates the error message:

```
    Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/organizations/589088021"]", found 0..
    Expected 0 to be >= 1.
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
    test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:46:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

Yet in development it works. The links that the error refers to are there and operational. Anyone got an idea about the cause?

The test:

```
get users_path
assert_template 'users/index'
User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user)
end

get organizations_path
assert_template 'organizations/index'
Organization.paginate(page: 1).each do |organization|             # THIS IS LINE 46!!
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', organization_path(organization)      # THIS IS LINE 47!!
end

get members_path
assert_template 'members/index'
Member.paginate(page: 1).each do |member|
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', member_path(member)
end
```

If I remove the second paragraph from the test, the test produces the same error for members. Yet, it doesn't generate the error for users (removing the second and thirs paragraph from the test, then the test passes). I don't find any differences in code between users and organizations/members to explain this. The only difference that I can think of is a 1:many relationship between organizations and members (users don't have a relationship) but I don't see how this has anything to do with it.

Organization index view:

```
<%= will_paginate @organizations %>

    <% @organizations.each do |organization| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <% if organization.avatar? %>
            <%= link_to image_tag(organization.avatar.url), organization_path(organization) %> <%= organization.org_name %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("profile.gif"), organization_path(organization) %> <%= organization.org_name %>
          <% end %>
        </td>
        <td>some other variables</td>
        <td><%= link_to image_tag("icon_delete.gif", title: "remove"), organization, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you certain?" } %>
        </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Organizations controller:

```
  def index
    @organizations = Organization.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end
```

**UPDATE:** The problem seems to be with the order in which it loads the organizations. Looking at the body using `puts @response.body` it shows the right number of organizations are returned and they do have the link. However, the organization for which the test says the link is missing is not part of `page: 1` and therefore indeed not included in the body. That it seems like a sorting problem, is confirmed by when I change line 46 of the test to:

```
Organization.where(email: !nil).each do |organization|
```

so that it looks at all the organizations, and therefore the order doesn't matter anymore. Then the test passes. I don't understand why the test expects a different organization to be part of `page: 1` and how I should adjust the test for it to work.

Once I start adding additional users to the users fixtures, the same problem arises for the first test regarding the User model.

Comment: In your test, after the `get organizations_path` line you can add `puts @response.body` to check out the HTML that's being generated and compare to the contents of `Organization.paginate(page: 1)` to help figure out what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and the body indeed includes the links just like in development. Each organization in the body has a line such as `<td> <a href="/organizations/97469533"><img alt="Profile" src="/assets/profile.gif" /></a> Company 16 </td>`. However, the test says `Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/organizations/589088021"]", found 0.` And indeed '589088021' is not in the body. So the test is expecting a link for an organization that doesn't seem to be part of the first page/pagination.

Comment: What is also striking, is what seems like a random order of the companies in the body. In the fixtures I create them using: `<% 35.times do |n| %> // organization_<%= n %>: // org_name: <%="Company #{n}" %> so you would neatly expect Company 1, 2, 3 etc. but this seems random. And I don't have a scope/order set in the organization model (for the member model I do have set a scope/order).

Comment: A relational database doesn't have an intuitive sense of what "ordered" is. If you don't tell it what to order by, the results can be random, depending on what the fastest way for the query optimizer of finding the results was.

Comment: How should I get my test to pass? I tried adding `default_scope -> { order('org_name') }` to the organization model, but that made no difference. Also, I would expect it not to matter to the test that the organizations are randomly ordered. All that should matter is that each record has a link, which they do. Why the test expects an organization in the body that isn't there, I don't understand.

Comment: What / how many elements does `Organization.paginate(page: 1)` return?

Comment: GIven `def index` in the organizations controller it should return 20 elements. I checked the body using `puts @response.body` and it indeed has 20 elements. So that seems right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I switched to kaminari for pagination. I still had the same problem: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548522/integration-test-assert-select-ahref-fails-for-paginated-pages). When I added order to the test code, the problem went away.