# Integration test: `assert_select 'a[href=?]'` fails for paginated pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, integration-testing

I have many integration tests that look something like:

```
first_page_of_users = User.page(1)                    # Using kaminari for pagination.
first_page_of_users.each do |user|
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user)
end
```

These tests fail with an error message such as:

```
Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/users/1"]", found 0..
```

I added `puts @response.body` to the tests to see the code that it responded with.

For all the users included in the response body it has correct hrefs, such as `href="/users/75938613"`. However, the numbers behind `/users/` are much higher, and "users1" is indeed not present (not just the url not present but the entire record isn't on that page). **If I ensure that there are only a few fixtures so that no pagination applies, the tests pass.** This makes me feel as if with pagination the order that `first_page_of_users = User.page(1)` applies differs from the order in records that `first_page_of_users.each do |user|` `assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user)` expects...

*What could be causing this error?* It applies to different pages and models of my app.

---

**Update:** For another model even when I try

```
Organization.all.each do |org|
  puts @response.body
  assert_select 'a[href=?]', organization_path(org)
end
```

I get the error:

```
Expected at least 1 element matching "a[href="/organizations/fix0"]",
```

The organization with the name "fix0" is not present at all in the body that it reponds with. My (shortened) fixtures are below and they confirm there should not be any organization with that name. Any idea what's going on?

```
one:
  name: abcd
  activated: true
  activated_at: 2015-04-16 11:38:53

two:
  name: efgh
  activated: true
  activated_at: 2015-04-16 11:38:53

<% 35.times do |n| %>
organization_<%= n %>:
  name: <%="fix#{n}" %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The <int>.times do |n| syntax starts at 0, so the organization 'fix0' is indeed being created. Why it's not showing up is another issue, what does your view rendering code look like?

Comment: Ah yes, of course it starts with 0, my mistake. It's a very long body response (grid view) but it includes 20 records: abcd, efgh, fix9,8,7,6,5,4,34,33,32,31,30,3,29,28,27,26,25,24. So no fix0. I've placed the full body [online](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8e5xmwtx0j2y5bj/code.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Okay, I'm a little curious about the sort order for these records, but assuming that's what you want to happen, to test this you need to make sure that the records you're testing are going to be present on the page--testing needs known conditions. So, either figure out which ones should show up on each page and have the test check each after getting the correct page, or have a small enough test set that they fit on one page. I personally prefer keeping the basic test set small--you can explicitly create more records for specific tests to verify that the pagination behaves like you want.

Comment: Thanks Brandy. If you add as an anwer, I'll accept it. To specify order int the test, would the following be correct syntax?: `Organization.order('organizations.name','desc').page(1).each do |organization|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When integration testing, it's important to keep track of what should show up where and test just that. Because we have too many records for the first page in this case, anything that would land on later pages will cause the failing test. As you suspect, something like this should verify that the first page of results is present:

```
Organization.order('organizations.name','desc').page(1).each do |organization|
     assert_select 'a[href=?]', organization_path(organization)
end
```

I recommend keeping a smaller data set for testing, because in this case you should also 'get' page two in your test and do the assertions above for 'page(2)' as well. This means this integration test has to issue two get requests (plus any setup you may need) and check the results, and making a habit of that can slow down your suite.

Comment: Thanks, a little correction, the first line I think needs to be: `Organization.order(:name).page(1).each do |organization|` or `Organization.order(name: :desc).page(1).each do |organization|`. Or any other alternative on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order.